# How do I test a component that fetches data from an external API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing

I'm trying to test a component that fetches data from Axios and it keeps giving me an error that the data fetched is undefined. I'm using jest and react testing library and also mocking Axios. The test result shows the Axios mock has been called but it keeps returning an undefined result. This is the code:

```
const lyricData = {
  message: {
    body: {
      lyrics: {
        lyric:
          "Do you love the rain, does it make you dance",
       lyrics_copyright:
          'Lyrics powered by www.musixmatch.com. This Lyrics is NOT for Commercial use and only 30% of the lyrics are returned.',

      }
    },
   }
};

afterEach(cleanup);
const props = {
  tracks: [
    {
      track: {
        track_id: 181987382,
        artist_name: 'sama',
        tracks: 'Hold my Liquor'
      }
    }
  ]
};

it('loads and displays lyric', async () => {
  axiosMock.get.mockResolvedValue({ data: lyricData });

  const url = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.lyrics.get?format=json&callback=callback&track_id=181987382&apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`;
  const { getByTestId, getByTitle } = render(<Lyrics {...props} />);

  const loading = getByTestId('loading');
  const title = getByTitle('Next Lyric');

  expect(loading).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(title).toBeInTheDocument();

  const resolvedValue = await waitForElement(() => getByTestId('lyrics'));

  expect(resolvedValue).toBeInTheDocument();

  expect(axiosMock.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(axiosMock.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(url);
});
```

it keeps saying `lyricData.lyric` in the component below is undefined

```
const [lyrics, setLyrics] = useState();
  const [copyright, setCopyRight] = useState();
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const trackName = tracks[count];
  const trackId = trackIds[count];

  const classes = useStyles();
  const rand = randomNumber(trackIds.length);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getLyrics = async (id) => {
      const lyricData = await generateLyric(id);
      setLyrics(lyricData.lyric);
      setCopyRight(lyricData.lyrics_copyright);
    };
    if (trackId) getLyrics(trackId);
  }, [trackId, trackIds]);
```

This is the generate lyric function:

```
export const generateLyric = async (trackId) => {
  const sanitizeLyrics = (lyric) => {
    const noNewLines = lyric.replace('/\n/g', ' ');
    const truncateLyric = noNewLines
      .split(' ')
      .splice(5, 55)
      .join(' ');
    return truncateLyric;
  };
  const url = `https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/track.lyrics.get?format=json&callback=callback&track_id=${trackId}&apikey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`;
  try {
    const { result } = await getApiData(url);
    const { lyrics_body, lyrics_copyright } = result.message.body.lyrics;
    const lyric = sanitizeLyrics(lyrics_body);
    return { lyric, lyrics_copyright };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: `await generateLyric(id);` doesn't return `lyricData.lyric`. `console.log` it out and post the code for that function too.

Comment: I've added the function. The function returns undefined

Comment: The data you're passing in for the test is wrong, then line `const { lyrics_body, lyrics_copyright } = result.message.body.lyrics;` sets `lyrics_body` to undefined, so `lyricData` in your test should be `message: { body: { lyrics: { lyrics_body: etc...`

Comment: Thanks, I've solved it. You're right ``lyricData`` object in the test wasn't structured properly